# Max in a sublist in a List

Tags: java, collections

example class

```
public class Marks{
  long subjectCode;
  float marks;
  string name;
}
```

Now I need to find the student who has got the most marks in each subjectCode. It would be awsome if someone knows a example where I can pass in subject code and get the topper in subject.

found a post to sort on multiple attribute [http://www.codejava.net/java-core/collections/sorting-a-list-by-multiple-attributes-example](http://mutlisort%20a%20list) 
But I need to find a max when I pass in a subject code

Comment: What data structure are the classes held in? What language? Is the collection you have sorted or unsorted? If it's unsorted is there any reason you can't sort the data in some sort of insert sort algorithm? Because that would make finding the top a lot easier. Is there any reason the class is built so that you have "Marks has a subject" instead of a "Subject has Marks"? It seems like the reason you are having problems here is because of architecture more than anything else.

Comment: data structure is a list.
Java.
unsorted.
I can sort but what I am looking for is max for each subject.
This is a quick made up example not actual code

Comment: John Coleman :
This is not a home work , I made this example up  to find a solution inside a much more complex code that is not related

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to guess a bit about input and output collections. Also naming is terrible.

```
    // Result: Max mark for each subject
    Map<Long, Marks> maxPerSubject = new HashMap<>();
    // Input (SubList in a List? One sublist per alumn?
    List<List<Marks>> listOfSubLists = new ArrayList<List<Marks>>();

    for (List<Marks> subList : listOfSubLists) {
        for (Marks currentMark : subList) {
            long subjectCode = currentMark.subjectCode;
            Marks currentMax = maxPerSubject.get(subjectCode);
            // If it is the first mark for the subject, or greater
            // If marks are equal, then first will be kept
            if (currentMax == null || currentMark.marks > currentMax.marks) {
                maxPerSubject.put(subjectCode, currentMark);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are using Java - I would recommend Java 8.

This is simple with Streams & Lambda.

```
long subjectCode = 10;
Collection<Marks> collection = getDataListFromSomewhere();
Optional<Marks> o = 
      collection.stream()
      .filter(item -> item.getSubjectCode() == subjectCode) //This filters the list to the class you are interested in
      .max(Comparator.comparing(item -> item.getMark())); //This looks for the max.

if(o.isPresent()){
    System.out.println(o.get().getName());
}
```

Comment: I wish I could go java 8 :( . The project in on Java 6 . Thaks for showing that on java 8 though.